# error message include_path, failed to open stream: No such file or directory on shared hosting

Tags: php

I have problem, on localhost my site is working, after upload on shared hosting there are show error message `include_path`,  failed to open stream: No such file or directory, for check please click link 
https://akunbet365.000webhostapp.com/logistogel/index.php

I have edit `.htaccses` file

> php_value include_path :/home/public_html/logistogel/:/home/public_html/logistogel/

and my code is

```
if (isset($_GET['pages'])) { 
   if ($_GET["pages"]=='home') 
      { 
        include "/pages/content/home.php"; 
      }
   elseif ($_GET["pages"]=='input') 
     { 
        include "/pages/content/input.php"
     }
```

}

but not working. Somebody please help me. I'm very confuse

Comment: can you show a little bit more of your code - especially the lines where you call `include()`

Comment: Welcome to SO, Can you please post your code ?

Comment: this is my code--> if (isset($_GET['pages'])) {
  
          if ($_GET["pages"]=='home') {
          include "/pages/content/home.php";
         
        }elseif ($_GET["pages"]=='input') {
              include "/pages/content/input.php";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are including `home.php` with an absolute path. But it looks like `/pages/content/home.php` is not a valid file path in your current infrastructure.

if the file home.php exists in `/home/public_html/logistogel/pages/content/home.php` then you should include it relative:

```
include "pages/content/home.php";
```

Absolute includes are also possible, but you have to be sure it's a valid path.